# Substring match in an arbitrary set of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table with around 10 columns containing various identifiers, both alphanumeric and numeric. I am writing a procedure which will allow a substring match to be performed across an arbitrary subset of those columns. For example, "the value in column B contains substring bSub AND the value in column D contains substring dSub AND the value in column G contains substring gSub".

The following works, but is blisteringly slow:

```
SELECT * FROM Table T
WHERE
  (@aSub IS NULL OR T.A LIKE CONCAT('%', @aSub, '%')) AND
  (@bSub IS NULL OR T.B LIKE CONCAT('%', @bSub, '%')) AND
  ...
  (@jSub IS NULL OR T.J LIKE CONCAT('%', @jSub, '%'))
```

Is there another way to structure this query which would be more performant? Or any techniques to speed things up? I believe that indexes won't help due to the substring match LIKE('%...).

Comment: The real solution to your problem is probably to structure your data better. You haven't shown us any sample data, so hard to guess whether there is a better solution. Sometimes what you have done is the only way to do it.

Comment: Full text search might help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, i'd say that string matching like this is always relatively slow.
With that being said, there are couple of things you could try:

1. Change LIKE to CHARINDEX. Since you don't actually match patterns, i suspect charindex is a bit more performant
2. Instead of checking OR @a IS NULL etc, build query dynamically from parameters that are actually not NULL. Something like:

```sql
declare @sql = 'select .... WHERE 1 = 1'
if @a is not null
 set @sql = @sql + ' and CHARINDEX(@a, a) > 0'

if @b is not null
 set @sql = @sql + ' and CHARINDEX(@b, b) > 0'

...
exec SP_EXECUTESQL @sql N@a nvarchar(100)', @a = @a, @b = @b...
```

This would only check relevant columns.

3. Create specific indexes for all or "most" searched for columns with the other needed columns as include. This might or might not help, but if you're lucky you can avoid full clustered index scan which is a lot more data to travel through than specific columns. This step is a bit tricky and might not help if SQL Server decides that it rather scans the clustered index anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that indexes won't help due to the substring match
> LIKE('%...).

Yep, sadly this is true and there's no easy way around this. You could do something advanced like [Trigram indexing](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-) but that's not a trivial task.

Without some sort of filter you need perform string evaluation and filtering on **every** relevant column for **every** row. This is no way to treat your optimizer.

So, if any of your columns are blank or null you can skip that row. With this in mind you can pre-filter these rows out. Here's some sample data to illustrate my point.

```
--==== Sample data
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
  ID INT IDENTITY,
  A  VARCHAR(10),
  B  VARCHAR(10),
  C  VARCHAR(10),
  BlankOrNull AS IIF(NULLIF(A,'') IS NULL OR 
                     NULLIF(B,'') IS NULL OR
                     NULLIF(C,'') IS NULL,1,0) PERSISTED,
  INDEX ix_blanknulls CLUSTERED(BlankOrNull,ID)
);
INSERT @t 
VALUES('00ABC','00ABCD00','777'),('ABCD','XXXXX','XZZZ'),('8','9',''),(NULL,NULL,NULL),
      ('ABC','XXXX',NULL),('ABCD-000','XXXXX00','XZZZ00');
```

Note the indexed computed column that I added name *BlankOrNull*. If any row contains a blank or NULL column you are done with that row, no further evaluation needed.

Without the indexed/computed column you would do this:

```
--==== Sample Variables
DECLARE 
  @aSub VARCHAR(10) = 'ABC',
  @bSub VARCHAR(10) = 'XXX',
  @cSub VARCHAR(10) = 'ZZZ';

SELECT t.* 
FROM (VALUES(@aSub,@bSub,@cSub)) AS s(A,B,C)
JOIN @t AS t
  ON  CHARINDEX(ISNULL(@aSub,T.A),T.A) > 0
 AND  CHARINDEX(ISNULL(@bSub,T.B),T.B) > 0
 AND  CHARINDEX(ISNULL(@cSub,T.C),T.C) > 0;
```

With the aforementioned index in place you can add a filter like so:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (VALUES(@aSub,@bSub,@cSub)) AS s(A,B,C)
JOIN @t AS t
  ON  CHARINDEX(ISNULL(@aSub,T.A),T.A) > 0
 AND  CHARINDEX(ISNULL(@bSub,T.B),T.B) > 0
 AND  CHARINDEX(ISNULL(@cSub,T.C),T.C) > 0
WHERE t.BlankOrNull = 0
```

Now let's run both and compare execution plans:

[image]

Next compare the actual number of rows each query processes:

[image]

Leveraging the index on the computed column we are able to process 1/2 the rows (based on my sample data, I don't know what the real stuff looks like.)